# An 'IN' inside an 'IFF' gives a syntax error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I cannot figure out why this is wrong. The syntax for an IFF is defined here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

[image]

Why does it complain about the IN operator?

Comment: What sql server version? As per documentation `iif` is available from 2012 and up!

Comment: What SSMS version as well? `select *, IIF(o.name IN ('xyz','bar'),1,0) from sys.objects o` works fine for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith, corrected. Thank you ;)

Comment: This works for me as well `SELECT Iif(1 IN ( 1, 2 ), 1, 0)`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the problem. I had been testing it on my own test environment, but a customer was using SQL Server 2008 SP3. So it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a version of SQL Server that does not support this function (pre SQL Server 2012). An alternative is to use a case statement like so:

```
Select NEWID(), m.MALEPUNKTYPE, 
       case when m.MALEPUNKTYPE in ('E17', 'E18') then 'D02' else null end
from AMALD m
```

This is supported from SQL Server 2005 onwards however it should work on earlier versions too

Comment: Neither `CASE` nor `IN` were new in 2005. The above code should work on SQL Server 2000 as well, possible earlier versions too. If your point is that SQL Server 2005 is the oldest supported version of SQL Server currently, it just seems like a setup for you to have to perpetually edit this question as older versions fall out of support.

Comment: Fair point, I just glanced to see what MSDN said about supported versions and noticed 2005 as the earliest. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. I've rewritten the query.